# Netty Proxy pipeline to support streaming and http caching

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to construct a proxy service with Netty that will support streaming calls and HTTP/1 traffic.

I've managed to do this successfully but ran into problems when I tried adding an HttpObjectAggregator to the pipeline. I need the Aggregator in order to construct a FullHttpResponse for reporting.

My current setup uses 2 ChannelInitializers and 2 business logic handlers

To initiate the proxy service:

```
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
    .childHandler(new SourceTransportHandlerInitializer())
    .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);

Channel channel;
try {
    channel = serverBootstrap.bind(localPort).sync().channel();
    channel.closeFuture().sync();
}catch (InterruptedException e){
    // oh no
}
```

SourceTransportHandlerInitializer.java

```
public class SourceTransportHandlerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeLine = socketChannel.pipeline();
        pipeLine.addLast(new HttpServerCodec(102400,102400,102400));
        pipeLine.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
        pipeLine.addLast(new SourceHandler());
        pipeLine.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
    }

}
```

SourceHandler.java

```
public class SourceHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private volatile Channel outboundChannel;

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext context) {
        final Channel inChannel = context.channel();

        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(inChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(context.channel().getClass())
                .handler(new TargetTransportHandlerInitializer(inChannel)) 
                .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(Constants.host, Constants.hostPort);
        outboundChannel = channelFuture.channel();

        channelFuture.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) channelFuture1 -> {
            if (channelFuture1.isSuccess()) {
                inChannel.read();
            } else {
                inChannel.close();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {
            //record request
        }

        if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
            outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) channelFuture -> {
                if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                    // flush and read data
                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    channelFuture.channel().close();
                }
            });
        } else {
            LOG.debug("SourceHandler did not read. Outbound Channel not active");
        }
    }

...

}
```

TargetTransportHandlerInitializer.java

```
public class TargetTransportHandlerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    protected final Channel inChannel;

    public TargetTransportHandlerInitializer (final Channel inChannel){
        this.inChannel = inChannel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeLine = socketChannel.pipeline();

        pipeLine.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec(102400, 102400, 102400)); 
        //pipeLine.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
        pipeLine.addLast(new TargetHandler(inChannel));
    }

}
```

TargetHandler.java

```
public class TargetHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final Channel inChannel;

    public TargetHandler(Channel inChannel) {
        this.inChannel = inChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse ) {
            //record response
        } else if (msg instanceof DefaultHttpResponse) {
            // convert to FullHttpResponse ?
        }

        inChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                ctx.channel().read();
            } else {
                future.channel().close();
            }
        });
    }

...

}
```

The `HttpObjectAggregator` in the source initializer pipeline causes no problems, and allows me to record the FullHttpRequest. If I comment `pipeLine.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));` in the `TargetTransportHandlerInitializer` class the proxy works perfect. If I remove that comment the streaming calls begin to fail. Without the aggregator the `msg` object is only a DefaultHttpResponse for HTTP/1 calls and I can't access the body and headers.

Do I need some kind of conditional pipeline where streaming avoids the aggregator? Or is there some alternative way to construct a `FullHttpResponse` from a `DefaultHttpResponse`?

I was really hoping I could just do this `FullHttpResponse full = HttpObjectAggregator.aggregate(default)` and call it a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by making a slight modification to the PortUnification example in the Netty project.

I updated the TargetTransportHandlerInitializer with the following:

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeLine = socketChannel.pipeline();

    pipeLine.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec(102400, 102400, 102400));
    pipeLine.addLast("switch", new SwitchHandler(inChannel));
    
}
```

`SwitchHandler` is a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` with the following:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    if (recordable(msg))
        createRecordingChannel(ctx);
    else
        createStreamingChannel(ctx);

    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
}

private void createRecordingChannel(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
    p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
    p.addLast("recordingHandler", new RecordingTargetHandler(inChannel));
    p.remove(this);
}

private void createStreamingChannel(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
    p.addLast("simpleHandler", new SimpleTargetHandler(inChannel));
    p.remove(this);
}
```

`recordable()` contains some business logic to look at the msg and make a determination. In my case was was looking at Headers.

My two new handlers look like the original TargetHandler, with different `channelRead` methods.

`SimpleTargetHandler` extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` with

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    inChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            ctx.channel().read();
        } else {
            future.channel().close();
        }
    });
}
```

`RecordingTargetHandler` extends `SimpleTargetHandler` with:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse ) {
        // record response
    }

    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Netty's HTTP codec works in two distinct ways:

- Aggregated: Use the object aggregator as you mention and it produces `FullHttpRequest`/`FullHttpResponse` objects.
- Non-aggregated (streaming): It produces distinct messages for headers, payload and trailers, which are `DefaultHttpRequest/Response`, `HttpContent` and `LastHttpContent`.

The idiomatic netty way of converting messages is to add a handler in the pipeline, so you would not have APIs like `FullHttpResponse full = HttpObjectAggregator.aggregate(default)` but instead you will insert a handler after the `HttpObjectAggregator` and receive the `FullHttpResponse` object.

The above is an either/or choice, so if you add an aggregator, handlers after the aggregator will only see aggregated messages whereas before the aggregator, they will see the distinct messages as I mention above.

The following example demonstrates of how to handle streaming messages:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientHandler.java#L30

Comment: This kind of just reiterates my problem, not answers it. I understand my current setup is an either/or issue. I want to know if there's some change I can do to have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: Not your setup, http handlers in netty is an either or choice. I also mention how you can access body in streaming mode which you asked in your question. Based on where you insert your handler, you can see streaming or aggregated message as I explain in the answer. There are no other options.